# How to get AD groups a user is in specifying username and domain

Tags: c#, asp.net, active-directory

I have a function that returns a list of AD groups a user is in.

```
    public static List<string> GetGroupNames(string userName)
    {

        using (var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, Environment.UserDomainName))
        {
            using (var userPrincipal = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, userName))
            {
                var groupSearch = userPrincipal.GetGroups(context);
                var result = new List<string>();
                groupSearch.ToList().ForEach(sr => result.Add(sr.SamAccountName));

                return result;
            }

        }
    }
```

This is working as I would expect.  I would like to update this function so I can pass it an LDAP path to specify the domain I want to query.

I have searched for hours and can find any pointers (even though I am sure the answer is out there somewhere!)  I would really appreciate any help here.

Comment: Maybe I got you wrong, but do you just want to replace the `Environment.UserDomainName` with a parameter?

Comment: @StrubT Its been one of those days! Yes that is exactly what I should be doing!! Duh! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just add a new parameter, let's say `string domainName` and pass it to `new PrincipalContext()` instead of `Environment.UserDomainName`.